# PHP: use id to another column

Tags: php

Ok, so i have a normal query that inserts to the database.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users_pm_in (uID, msg) VALUES ('$uID', '$msg')");
```

Now this table has also a column called "id" with auto_increment & primary key.

When it inserts it auto makes number for the column in the row. Now I want this number, and put it in column dialog, in the same row. So the inserted row have the same number/id in "id" and "dialog". How can i do that?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that? Sounds like a bad idea...

Comment: If you want uID to be same as id, why are you even using a different field?

Comment: I hope you sanitized those variables before you put them into the query string. Otherwise you gonna get a [lot of fun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) when people start writing messages that contain single quotes.

Comment: $uID and $msg is real escaped

Comment: @Fredley I am making an PM system that people and can have different dialog with eachother. I use the id that gets created as the dialog_id also, to know what messages there is in the dialog.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if this can be done in one query (or why you even want to do this), but you can use this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users_pm_in (uID, msg) VALUES ('$uID', '$msg')");
mysql_query("UPDATE users_pm_in SET dialog = id WHERE id = '".mysql_insert_id()."');
```

Be sure to escape the variables properly also.

Comment: ok thank you. Variables, $uID and $msg? they are real_escape.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easier to remove the autoincrement and add the id+dialog value yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Check out mysql_insert_id()

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, altough it's not very efficient...

Supose you have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `a` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `b` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE=MyISAM
ROW_FORMAT=DEFAULT
```

You can perform the following query:

```
INSERT INTO test (a, b) SElECT IFNULL((MAX(id) +1),1), 200 FROM test;
```

Notice that "200" is some random value that will be inserted on "b" column.